# Quotation Question in APA Format Critical Analysis

Tags: academic-writing, punctuation, apa

I am writing a critical analysis of an article involving a "rule". Every time the authors mention the word "rule", it is in quotations. Would it be correct to also include "rule" in quotations every time I mention it in my paper, or to include it without?

Answer (score 1):

I would italicize the term in APA style, and in other styles as well.

According to the [APA style blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/04/using-italics-for-technical-or-key-terms.html) you only have to italicize once.